# MongoDB hosting on Digital Ocean

Tags: mongodb, digital-ocean

I just signed up on digital ocean and about to purchase an hourly based subscription for basic package. 
20GB SSD Disk, 512 MB RAM etc

My question is that how can I deploy my mongodb in this server machine? Or is there any proper tutorial which can guide me through this. Currently my db is hosted in MongoLab and server is hosted at Azure but its getting quite expensive for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to https://www.digitalocean.com/community there are lot of tutorial for the most common deployments that you can do in a droplet.

[image]

Also, (if you don't know it) you can create a droplet with MongoDB installed:

[image]

Comment: Thanks this helps but shouldn't I select "Node on ..." ?

Comment: yes, you can use whatever you want: only MongoDB installation, the Node.js droplet, a MEAN stack installation...

Comment: ScaleGrid provides fully managed mongodb hosting platform (https://scalegrid.io/mongodb/digitalocean.html) on DigitalOcean. It includes dedicated hosting, full MongoDB admin access and advanced mangement features (disclaimer, I'm the founder of ScaleGrid)

Answer (score 0):

Droplets are the way to go in Digital Ocean. They are easy to create and even destroy.

Once you get a droplet, carry out the following:

- Remote into the droplet.
- Download mongodb from the shell.
- Install it.